# OData not operator, or how to filter for all items which not startswith(...)

Tags: odata

I am using the SharePoint REST API, which is similar to OData, but currently I don't even know the standard OData way. I would like to filter items that do not start with a certain string pattern. How is the 'not' operator written in OData? All references list 'and' and 'or' operators and 'ne' operators, but I cannot find one for 'not'.

Neither of the following work:

a)

```
  not startswith(field, 'pattern')
```

b)

```
 startswith(field, 'pattern') ne true // Yes I know there is no 'true' boolean literal.
```

Answer (score 5):

Even though the diagram from [Use OData query operations in SharePoint REST requests](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142385(v=office.15).aspx) illustrates that the proper syntax for `startswith` operator is:

```
filter=startswith(PropertyName, 'String') Eq Boolean
```

it seems the only syntax it accepts is:

```
filter=startswith(PropertyName, 'String')
```

For example, the request:

```
/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/Pages?$filter=startswith(Title,'SharePoint') eq false
```

returns pages those `Title` does not start with `SharePoint`

But the same request using `_api` service endpoint

```
/_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('Pages')/items?$filter=startswith(Title,'SharePoint') eq false
```

returns `The query is not valid` exception.

**Solution**

Utilize `listdata.svc` endpoint since it **fully supports** the syntax of `startswith` operator as specified in [OData specification](http://www.odata.org/).